# Problem adjusting scrollbar after images have been loaded on page

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser, scrollbar

**Problem description:** I got a **page with a table** containing **text** and **thumbnails**. Usually the table contains more entries than would fit on the screen leading to a **scrollbar on the right side**. No Problem so far. When loading the page or choosing the next page of the table (pagination) the table gets rendered - **the scrollbar is at the bottom of the page where i would like it to be after complete load**. Then the **thumbnails** are getting shown. Due to the fact that they are a bit bigger in size than the text in the table the table gets bigger in heigth leading to the scrollbar being set somewhere in the middle of the page.

Page and table after the images have been loaded, as you can see the scrollbar is somewhere in the middle (vertical) of the page:
[image]

I do not want to fiddle around with the thumbnail size. Customers are used to the actual design and image/icon sizes.

Usign the pagination function the table is the only element that gets replaced ont he page. "onload" on tables does not work unfortunatly.

**What can i do to have the scrollbar appear after the images have been loaded (leading to the correct placement of the scrollbar)?
Is there a way to set the scrollbar to the bottom of the page after the table has been fully loaded?**

Answer (score 2):

There are jQuery plugins to wait for all images to be loaded, but I couldn't get them working on the quick, maybe you can: [here](https://gist.github.com/268257) and [here](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/blob/master/ahpi.imgload.js).

However, you also could use the following hack: watch for the table height and if it changes, scroll to the bottom:

```
var lastHeight;
function watchTable(){
    var currentHeight = $('#myTable').height();
    if(currentHeight !== lastHeight){
        lastHeight = currentHeight;
        $('#myDiv').scrollTop(currentHeight);
    }
}

setInterval(watchTable, 100);
```

see my [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/T7agU/1/) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to set the widths of thumbnails in HTML or CSS, if all the thumbnails are of the same size, you can just add the style like

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Or, if they size can vary, you must add `width` and `height` attributes to the ` tag.

Another solution is to:

Look at the document's scrolltop on DOMload, and look if it's at the bottom, then on `onload` event (which would be fired when all the images loaded) check again and if scroll to the desired position if needed.

But I recommend always set the dimensions for images, so the page wouldn't jump when they are loaded.

*Edit:* If you're loading images dynamically, you can do two things:

1. Preload images and then insert them with the right dimensions.
2. Use `onload` for images, however, you still would need to use the `document.createElement('img')`, so you could be sure that all the images are loaded.

Anyway, in these cases you should use something like that for each image:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = function () {
    // Image is loaded
};
image.src = 'test.jpg';
```

Note, that you must set `.src` after attaching the event, or there could be some problems in Opera.

Comment: +1 thx for the answer, but i do not want to change the thumbnail size. i was thinking and experimenting about the onload event too

Comment: problem here is that using the pagination feature (only the table gets replaced) onload is not usable cause it works not on tables.

Comment: Edited an answer. In short: you can use `onload` events for images themselves too, so after all of them are loaded you could fix the scrollbar.

Comment: hmmm, depending on the settings the table may hold more than 100 images, looks like this could get a bit messy(?)

Comment: Well, if you'd do this in cycle (count all the images you're adding, attach all cycle the events, in each event decrement the number and when it become zero — fix the scroll. But if there could be a way to preset the dimensions for each image — it'd be much cleaner.